# I need to import a .aar (Java Archive) file into my Xamarin Android (Blank App - Native) project and iOS naitive Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, dependencies, aar

I need to import an AAR (Java Archive) file into my Xamarin Android (Blank App - Native) project and iOS. I am new to Xamarin and I am using an API that is not available in the Xamarin NuGet Manager.

I have an AAR file with classes that I need to use in my project but I can't find a way to implement that. How should I import this AAR?

In native Android, I usually add the file in my dependencies in Gradle, by referencing the package name. (com.aartoimplement.classes), the same way I'd add a dependency for a RecyclerView or the Glide library. How do I add and use the classes in this AAR file with Xamarin?

Comment: First, the `.aar` will not work on iOS, so there is there is nothing to "import" there. For your `Xamarin.Android` project, you will need to create another `Xamarin.Android` project, a *Binding Project*, and import the `.aar` into that project and write any transformations that might be needed, Xamarin has guides to walk you through the process: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/